# Create a reference to the selected tab in my TabViewController?

Tags: ios

## RWGameData.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class RWGameData;
@protocol RWGameStateProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)StateUpdateForGameData:(RWGameData*)data;
@end

@interface RWGameData : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (weak) id<RWGameStateProtocol> delegate;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long regularBubbleCount;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long premiumBubbleCount;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long megaBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubblersUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier;
@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleBankUpgradeTier;

@property (assign, nonatomic) int megaBubblePopValue;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int bubbleFactoryTickValue;

@property (assign, nonatomic) long bubbleBankCapacity;

@property (assign, nonatomic) int collectionBallsQuantity;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int collectionGlowsticksQuantity;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int collectionFlowersQuantity;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int collectionStuffedAnimalsQuantity;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int collectionEasterEggsQuantity;

@property (assign, nonatomic) int currentXP;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int targetXP;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int level;

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL dataIsInitialized;

+(instancetype)sharedGameData;
-(void)reset;
-(void)save;

-(void)timerSetup;
-(void)timerCalled;

@end
```

## RWGameData.m

```
#import "RWGameData.h"

@implementation RWGameData

static NSString* const SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey = @"regularBubbleCount";
static NSString* const SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey = @"premiumBubbleCount";

static NSString* const SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"megaBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey = @"bubblersUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey = @"mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey = @"bubbleBankUpgradeTier";

static NSString* const SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey = @"megaBubblePopValueKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey = @"bubbleFactoryTickValueKey";

static NSString* const SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey = @"bubbleBankCapacityKey";

static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionBallsQuantityKey = @"collectionBallsQuantityKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionGlowsticksQuantityKey = @"collectionGlowsticksQuantityKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionFlowersQuantityKey = @"collectionFlowersQuantityKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionStuffedAnimalsQuantityKey = @"collectionStuffedAnimalsQuantityKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionEasterEggsQuantityKey = @"collectionEasterEggsQuantityKey";

/*static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionBallsModifierKey = @"collectionBallsModifierKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataCollectionGlowsticksModifierKey = @"collectionGlowsticksModifierKey";
static NSString* const SSGameCollectionFlowersModifierKey = @"collectionFlowersModifierKey";
static NSString* const SSGameCollectionStuffedAnimalsModifierKey = @"collectionStuffedAnimalsModifierKey";
static NSString* const SSGameCollectionEasterEggsModifierKey = @"collectionEasterEggsModifierKey";*/

static NSString* const SSGameDataCurrentXPKey = @"currentXPKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataTargetXPKey = @"targetXPKey";
static NSString* const SSGameDataLevelKey = @"levelKey";

static NSString* const SSGameDataIsInitializedKey = @"dataIsInitializedKey";

+ (instancetype)sharedGameData {
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [self loadInstance];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)reset {
    self.regularBubbleCount = 0;
    self.premiumBubbleCount = 0;

    self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubblersUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = 0;
    self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier = 0;

    self.megaBubblePopValue = 1;
    self.bubbleFactoryTickValue = 1;

    self.bubbleBankCapacity = 500;

    self.collectionBallsQuantity = 0;
    self.collectionGlowsticksQuantity = 0;
    self.collectionFlowersQuantity = 0;
    self.collectionStuffedAnimalsQuantity = 0;
    self.collectionEasterEggsQuantity = 0;

    self.currentXP = 0;
    self.targetXP = 83;
    self.level = 1;

    self.dataIsInitialized = true;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.regularBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.premiumBubbleCount forKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.megaBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubblersUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleBankUpgradeTier forKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.megaBubblePopValue forKey: SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleFactoryTickValue forKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.bubbleBankCapacity forKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.collectionBallsQuantity forKey: SSGameDataCollectionBallsQuantityKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.collectionGlowsticksQuantity forKey: SSGameDataCollectionGlowsticksQuantityKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.collectionFlowersQuantity forKey: SSGameDataCollectionFlowersQuantityKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.collectionStuffedAnimalsQuantity forKey: SSGameDataCollectionStuffedAnimalsQuantityKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.collectionEasterEggsQuantity forKey: SSGameDataCollectionEasterEggsQuantityKey];

    [encoder encodeDouble:self.currentXP forKey: SSGameDataCurrentXPKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.targetXP forKey: SSGameDataTargetXPKey];
    [encoder encodeDouble:self.level forKey:SSGameDataLevelKey];

    [encoder encodeBool:self.dataIsInitialized forKey: SSGameDataIsInitializedKey];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _regularBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataRegularBubbleCountKey];
        _premiumBubbleCount = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataPremiumBubbleCountKey];

        _megaBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMegaBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubblersUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubblersUpgradeTierKey];
        _mysteryBubbleUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMysteryBubbleUpgradeTierKey];
        _bubbleBankUpgradeTier = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankUpgradeTierKey];

        _megaBubblePopValue = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataMegaBubblePopValueKey];
        _bubbleFactoryTickValue = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleFactoryTickValueKey];

        _bubbleBankCapacity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataBubbleBankCapacityKey];

        _collectionBallsQuantity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCollectionBallsQuantityKey];
        _collectionGlowsticksQuantity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCollectionGlowsticksQuantityKey];
        _collectionFlowersQuantity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCollectionFlowersQuantityKey];
        _collectionStuffedAnimalsQuantity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCollectionStuffedAnimalsQuantityKey];
        _collectionEasterEggsQuantity = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCollectionEasterEggsQuantityKey];

        _currentXP = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataCurrentXPKey];
        _targetXP = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataTargetXPKey];
        _level = [decoder decodeDoubleForKey: SSGameDataLevelKey];

        _dataIsInitialized = [decoder decodeBoolForKey: SSGameDataIsInitializedKey];
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString*)filePath
{
    static NSString* filePath = nil;
    if (!filePath) {
        filePath =
        [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject]
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];
    }
    return filePath;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
    NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [RWGameData filePath]];
    if (decodedData) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }

    return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (void)timerSetup { // to be called from delegate didFinishLaunching….
    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCalled) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerCalled
{
    //NSLog(@"Timer Called");]
    if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier > 0) {
        if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount < [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity) {
            [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount += [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryTickValue;
            [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];


        } else {
            NSLog(@"Capacity Reached! Capacity: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity);
        }
        [self.delegate StateUpdateForGameData:self];

    } NSLog(@"Regular Bubble Count: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);
}

@end
```

## PrimaryViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"

@interface PrimaryViewController : UIViewController <RWGameStateProtocol>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *regularBubLabel;

@end
```

I would like to be able to change the value of regularBubLabel from within the timerCalled method. Thank you for your time.

Included the entirety of my RWGameData class as it was requested. Thanks.

## AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RWGameData.h"
#import "PrimaryViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) RWGameData *gameData;


@end
```

Then see +(instancetype)loadInstance of #RWGameData.m

Comment: Please clarify. Xcode is the IDE (computer program designed to write other programs for specific environments), not the language or OS. Do you want to reference the Xcode tab that is currently open, or the tab of the UITabViewController?

Comment: @CaptJak Updated. I am referring to the selected tab in my tab view controller.

Comment: Why do you need a reference. From where are you trying to change the value of a label?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a difficult time explaining what I want. From my custom class, I am attempting to change the text value of a label that has been declared and initialized from another class. For every second that passes, my goal is to be able to update this label from my custom class.

Comment: We need more information about this custom class. What is it a subclass of? How and where are you creating it?

Comment: Updated for clarity.

Comment: how you are presenting the PrimaryViewController in TabbarController or navigation or just presenting it.You need a reference to PrimaryViewController.

Comment: I don't think I'm referencing it at all. I need to be able to dynamically reference whatever tab is selected because the label will need to update on whatever tab is opened.

Comment: are you using TabbarController? where is the outlet of TabbarController saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide more details of what you are trying to achieve.

If I understand correctly you want to know which tab is active
all you have to do is get **tab.selectedIndex** property which will return back to you int representing the index of activTabView then you can do anything with it such as change the Text of the selected index

Hope this help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a difficult time explaining what I want. From my custom class, I am attempting to change the text value of a label that has been declared and initialized from another class. For every second that passes, my goal is to be able to update this label from my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see that your PrimaryViewController is confirming the protocol for RWGameData i.e

```
@interface PrimaryViewController : UIViewController <RWGameStateProtocol>
```

so, set the delegate of RWGameData to PrimaryViewController Object, then implement this delegate method in PrimaryViewController.m like

```
-(void)StateUpdateForGameData:(RWGameData*)data
{
  //now update label
  self.regularBubLabel.text = @"asdasd";
}
```

Edit:

In PrimaryViewController.m  viewDidLoad method add this line

```
[RWGameData  sharedGameData].delegate = self;
```

timercalled method should be like

```
-(void)timerCalled
{
    //NSLog(@"Timer Called");]
    if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryUpgradeTier > 0) {
        if ([RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount < [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity) {
            [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount += [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleFactoryTickValue;
            [[RWGameData sharedGameData] save];


        } else {
            NSLog(@"Capacity Reached! Capacity: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].bubbleBankCapacity);
        }

  if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(StateUpdateForGameData:)])
        [self.delegate StateUpdateForGameData:self];

    } NSLog(@"Regular Bubble Count: %li", [RWGameData sharedGameData].regularBubbleCount);
}
```

Comment: My class doesn't seem to be able to identify UIViewController. It says it is an undeclared type? I assume I need an import.

Comment: you need a reference to PrimaryViewController is there any property in which your PrimaryViewController is saved.?

Comment: I did the following but it doesn't seem to have worked. It does not update in real time. It does, however, update when I click over to a new tab and go back to the PrimaryViewController. This is because I update the label in my viewDidAppear method. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think the delegates are not been called by RWGameData, You should properly set the delegates, add a break point to     [self.delegate StateUpdateForGameData:self]; line and investegate further that is it calling the delegate or not. And in -(void)StateUpdateForGameData:(RWGameData*)data check the data object if it got proper values.

Comment: just post the code where you are creating RWGameData object and assigning the delegate to it.

Comment: I think I added what you want.

Comment: My friend post the code where you have created RWGameData object. its just .h and .m file , I want to see the code for gameData object creation and initialization.

Comment: I see. I've updated the thread again. Thanks for sticking with me on this one.

Comment: This should work now, try to add break point in delegate method and timer called to make sure delegate is properly set to PrimaryViewController

Comment: I get the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PrimaryViewController StateUpdateForGameData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffb29f2aa00'

Comment: add -(void)StateUpdateForGameData:(RWGameData*)data method in primaryviewcontroller as I said in answer, also updated the answer.

Comment: Okay. I did add the method to the PrimaryViewController, both in the header file and the class file. I've updated as you suggested but the label still doesn't update every second, or at all for that matter. Perhaps I missed a step? The application no longer crashes, so that's a plus.

Comment: It seems that the following line never returns true: if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(StateUpdateForGameData:)])